# Login to citrix machine using Robot framework

Tags: robotframework, citrix

We are trying to automate a few Test Cases which require login to a Citrix machine using Robot framework.

Could someone please help provide a sample example to automate the same.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
-kranti

Answer (score 0):

You can create a keyword for Login into Citrix Machine which you can then call in your TestCases.

An example is shown as below:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${Citrix_machine}    192.168.0.1
${username}    user
${password}    password

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Open Connection    ${Citrix_machine}
    Login    ${username}    ${password}
```

If you want to create a keyword of login then you can use the following steps:-

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${Citrix_machine}    192.168.0.1
${username}    user
${password}    password

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
Login into Cluster

*** Keywords ***
Login into Cluster
    Open Connection    ${Citrix_machine}
    Login    ${username}    ${password}
```